# ZendFramework error: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided

Tags: zend-framework, getaddrinfo

I install MySQL, php with nginx on mac os x. This is the first time that I install on a Mac, so far I've used linux.

I got this error when i try to run my zend application.

I tried that instead of localhost enter ip adress and 127.0.0.1, But i get the same error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli_Exception'
>   with message 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename
>   nor servname provided, or not known' in
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php:333 Stack
>   trace:
>
> 0 ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(304):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->_connect()  1
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php(194):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->getConnection()  2
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(823):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->describeTable('site_page', NULL)  3
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(862):
>   Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata()  4
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(969):
>   Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()  5
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php(100):
>   Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info()  6 in
>   ZendFramework-1.10.7/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php on line 333

All components are installed from this -> http://blog.frd.mn/install-nginx-php-fpm-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-os-x-mavericks-using-homebrew/ tutorial.

phpMyAdmin is installed and working. But i can't run my zend application.

Version: OS X Yosemite 10.12.2

ZendFramework: 1.10.7

PHP: 5.6.7

MySQL: 14.14 Distrib 5.6.23, for osx10.10 (x86_64) using EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 0):

I use textedit app that is built into OS X then I disable the feature called "Smart Quotes" from the preferences of TextEdit and then I have to replace all the existing quotes in the code. All is ok now.